# How can I write on a PDF with the free version of OneNote?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-onenote

OneNote has become free recently. I wonder, how I can write (making hand-notes, using my digitizer) on a PDF with that fancy tool?

I've searched for an import function, but I didn't found any.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "write on"? Do you mean mark up a document? Fill it out? Edit one? Create one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, open the PDF file with your normal pdf reader, for example Adobe Acrobat Reader, or Foxit Reader.

From here `print` the file to `OneNote` or if the option `Send to One Note` is available, use this one instead.

Now that the file is in One note, you should have one or more images of the PDF pages. Using the tools available in One Note, you can draw/type over the existing pages. Then you can `file`->`save as` to save it as pdf file.